# How to retain open/close animation with frameless window [QT/C++]

Tags: c++, windows, qt, titlebar, qdialog

On Windows, whenever a window is opened or closed, it has a small/quick inflation/deflation + fade animation.

In QT, this effect occurs with most normal windows and dialogs. However, if one uses `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` or `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` as window flags to remove the title bar, the window also loses the previously mentioned animation.

I would really like to remove the title bar in order to create my own title bar (with custom close button, title information, custom theme, etc), but no combination of window flags and/or classes seem to work.

Yet I've other programs (Google Chrome, Visual Studio, etc) use their own custom title bars and still have the fading animation.

Is there anyway around this issue?

Demonstration using Window Flags example project:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCKyM5emGZs

PS: I am aware I could generate my own animations; however, it's impossible to replicate the smoothness and compatibility provided by the default animation. As a result, I would prefer to only do so as a last resort.

Comment: I think since qt uses native calls to OS, it's not possible. Only way to fix is as you said, to add custom animations

Comment: There's [AnimateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669.aspx), although I don't know if that still works with the DWM, or whether the DWM offers a replacement call.

Comment: I don't think it is realistic to forgo OS window decorations and expect to keep the behavior it comes with. You will most likely have to make due with what you can fake.